JTOpen Bulk configuration
I wanted to ask something related to the Java AS400 connection driver, that is, JTOpen, and it is about whether it has a URL parameter similar to that of PostgreSQL:
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db?reWriteBatchedInserts=true
That allows doing SQL inserts like these:
INSERT INTO table (name, value) values ​​("name1", "value1"), ("name2", "value2"), ("name3", "value3")

instead of doing them like this:
INSERT INTO table (name, value) values ​​("name1", "value1")
INSERT INTO table (name, value) values ​​("name2", "value2")
INSERT INTO table (name, value) values ​​("name3", "value3")

I am looking for an answer regarding this, because I am looking to optimize inserts in a database, I just want to know if there is a parameter that I can provide to make this possible, or if There is no parameter or where I could ask to get an answer, I have been searching for days and I can't find anything.

It is 20 years since I used an AS400, so I don't know what is possible in its dialect of SQL and its JDBC Driver, so this is guesswork:
1. The multiple insert sytnax
If that syntax of supporting multiple record insert is supported in the AS400 SQL Shell, then I don't see why a Java driver cannot handle it. The JDBC driver would just see this as a very long statement.
2. Batch support
I would think it likely that your JDBC driver will support the Batch method of inserting.  You prepare a statement ready for just one set of column values, then supply a collection of data that are sent in batches to the database.  This is more aligned to how a java program would send data and may give equally better performance than discrete inserts. Read a tutorial here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jdbc-batch-inserts

That same thing that it says on that page is what I'm looking for "multi-value inserts", but on the page it only talks about PostgreSQL, it varies from one database to another, and I know that AS400 supports it because I have used those syntaxes in it as such, but I don't know how to configure it, I can't find documentation on it.

The JTOpen driver (used to?) have a setting

"use block update" - This property allows the toolbox JDBC driver to
use a block update mode when updating blocks of data into the
database. This is an optimized version of the batch update.  Default -
false

But it doesn't show in the latest version of the documentation.  A quick search of the code shows it's still an acceptable parameter, but I don't see where it's actually used.
In any event,
INSERT INTO table (name, value) values ​​("name1", "value1"), ("name2", "value2"), ("name3", "value3")

Is a perfectly acceptable statement, and has been for a long time without needing to modify the connection properties.
Additionally, JTOpen supports the standard JDBC AddBatch() method and it's supporting methods as shown in this answer.

Well, the documentation say this:  "Note: The following list does not include DataSource properties." Well, I know that this SQL statement is valid, but the batch by default does several inserts in a single block: begin transaction
end transaction
which is fine, but I wanted to see if it was possible to do multi-value in Java like in postgresql

And I said that the multi value statement would work.
